# Can Spring Boot serve precompressed assets

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm wondering if Spring or Spring Boot supports serving precompressed resources.

For example nginx supports this with the `gzip_static on` flag.
When a client sends the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header, nginx checks if there is a file with the requested name and the ending '.gz'. If such a file exists nginx serves that to the client and saves some CPU cycles because it does not have to compress it on the fly.

Can I do the same with Spring and compress all my files in the static folder and the embedded web server serves them like nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Spring supports this use case with the 
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.GzipResourceResolver

This resolver searches for files ending with `.gz` when the client sends the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header.

This was introduced with Spring 4.1.

You can enable this resolver with a resource configuration:

```
@Configuration
class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(false).addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver());
  }
}
```

Spring Boot 1.4 added auto configuration support for the gzip resolver. Add this to your application.properties file and Spring Boot automatically registers the GzipResourceResolver

```
spring.resources.chain.gzipped=true
```

Comment: This is `spring.web.resources.chain.compressed` now. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.web.resources.chain.compressed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure `gzip` compression for specific resources and their mime-types.

Here is what it looks like if you use *application.yml* file:

```
server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript
    min-response-size: 2048
```

And here is similar configuration for *application.properties* file:

```
server.compression.enabled=true # If response compression is enabled.
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript # Comma-separated list of MIME types that should be compressed.
server.compression.min-response-size=2048 # Minimum response size that is required for compression to be performed.
```

You can define with `server.compression.mime-types` property which assets have to be compressed, here in this example I have used some defaults from [Appendix A. Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)
.

Here you can see `style.css` (439 KB) file from some demo Spring Boot app with no compression:

[image]

And here the same file but with compression enabled (65.8 KB):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But that is not exactly what I was looking for. I want to serve precompressed resources. I gzip the resources during the build process. nginx can then serve these without compressing the resources on the fly. The main idea is to save some CPU cycles, when you need to serve a lot of requests. And I was wondering if Spring Boot can do the same

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can.

this solution is similar to JGrassini, but using EncodedResourceResolver your application will be able to serve already compressed .gz and .br files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .setOrder(-1)
            .addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/where are your already compressed file to serve/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new EncodedResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

you can read about: [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-developing-web-applications)

Answer (score -2):

As far I know you haven’t such possibility but you can do this quite easily yourself. I think this is actually should be implemented on Tomcat or Jetty level. If you implemented the filter then please contribute because I’m looking too.

**UPD** EncodedResourceResolver